# Is it possible to use BCP In with named pipe in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bcp, jq

I have a input JSON file which I want to load into SQL Server Table.
Currently I am following below steps:

1)  Convert JSON file to Flat Structure using JQ utility. (http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

2)  Store the output of JQ into Flat File

3)  Load flat file into SQL Table using BCP

```
BCP Database.Schema.Table in "\\SharedDirectory\InputFileName.txt" -T -S "Server" -w -t ~ -r \n
```

Is it possible to skip Step 2) and load output of JQ directly into SQL Server table using BCP?
I am trying to run something like below command:

```
JQCommand | BCP Database.Schema.Table in -T -S "Server" -w -t ~ -r \n
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what I can see in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx), it seems like BCP only accepts files for inputs.

For Windows, there is a special file called `con` that could be used to capture stdin (similar to `/dev/stdin`).  Try using that.

```
JQCommand | BCP Database.Schema.Table in con -T -S "Server" -w -t ~ -r \n
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, Using special file con did not work. I received this error: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible - but the pipe must be marked as `InOut`.  Example:

```
var pipeId = $"bcp_{Guid.NewGuid():n}";
Thread copyThread;
using (var np = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeId))
{
    copyThread = new Thread(_1 =>
    {
        np.WaitForConnection();

        using (var dst = File.Create("out.txt"))
        {
            np.CopyTo(dst, 4096);
        }
    });
    copyThread.Start();

    var bcp = Process.Start(
        @"bcp.exe",
        $@"dbo.Table out \\.\pipe\{pipeId} -S Server -U sa -P password -w -t,");
    bcp.WaitForExit();
}
copyThread.Join();
```